# How to convert a row of a sqLite db into an arrayList and then choose a random element of the list?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am currently working on an app, the final goal of it is that you click a button and it will display a random challenge that is stored in the sqlLite DB.

I can't manage to take a random row of it, even with all the tutorials and the posts on StackOverflow talking about it, maybe my current level and knowledge are to small to make it work. Perhaps the fact that I use it in a Fragment can make it even harder.

Because I can't manage to take directly a random row in my DB, I thought about using an arrayList to store the string stored in the column "Gage" of all the rows of my db, and then take a random element of this arrayList.

So, if someone knows what is wrong, please help me.

**Data Base Class**

```java
package com.thebatz.game20;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class PenanceDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATA_BASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Penance";
    private static final String ID = "ID";
    private static final String Gage = "GAGE";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Penance.db";

    public PenanceDB(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATA_BASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase dbPen) {
        dbPen.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME+ "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, GAGE TEXT, TIME INTEGER)" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dbPen, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        dbPen.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(dbPen);
    }

    public boolean insertPen(String gageNom) {

        SQLiteDatabase dbPen = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Gage, gageNom);


           long result =  dbPen.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

            if(result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
    }

    public Cursor getDataPen(){
        SQLiteDatabase dbPen = this.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor res = dbPen.rawQuery("select * from " +TABLE_NAME, null);
            return res;
    }

    public boolean penitenceUpdate(String id, String penitence) {
        SQLiteDatabase dbPen = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(ID, id);
        contentValues.put(Gage, penitence);

        dbPen.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
package com.thebatz.game20;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.String;


public class GameActivity extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_game, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        final Button btnViewPen = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnGamePen);
        final Button btnViewAw = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnGameAw);

        final PenanceDB myPen = new PenanceDB(getActivity());
        final AwardDB myAw = new AwardDB(getActivity());

        final List<String> Penance = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> Award = new ArrayList<>();

        btnViewPen.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       Cursor res = myPen.getDataPen();

                        if(res.getCount() == 0){
                            showMessage("Erreur 404", "Base de données vide");
                            return;
                        }
//Putt sqlite data into an array list
                        while (res.moveToNext()) {
                            Penance.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Gage")));
                        }
//Take a randome one
                        int iD = new Random().nextInt(Penance.size());
                        String item = Penance.get(iD);

//call the methode to display it

                        showMessage("Gages: ", item);
                    }
                }
        );

        btnViewAw.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor res = myAw.getDataRec();

                        if(res.getCount() == 0){
                            showMessage("Erreur 404", "Base de données vide");
                            return;
                        }

                        while (res.moveToNext()) {
                            Award.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Gage")));
                        }

                        int iD = new Random().nextInt(Award.size());
                        String item = Award.get(iD);

                        showMessage("Gages", item);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void showMessage(String title, String Message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

**XML file of the fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.thebatz.game20.GameActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGamePen"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="138dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="@string/p_nitence"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGameAw"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="@string/r_compences"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnGamePen"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.509" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: did you try to query the sqlite, create a local list, then do a forloop for every item in the sql db, add to the list? shouldnt be too difficult.

Comment: Thank you so much ! As you told me, I query through the sqlite database and add it to a local array list with a while loop that has as condition (cursor.moveToNext()). After that I return a random element of this list and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating the random number before executing the SQL command - Then when you use your SELECT statement you could include the random number variable as the ID to query?